# Make <footer> element minimize unless free space is available

Tags: html, css, footer

I need a footer to appear when the viewer is at the bottom of the page. So if you haven't scrolled to the bottom yet, you do not see the footer. Simple enough; but I'm barely learning and therefore uncertain.

I'll put my code here:

```css
footer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #bdbdbd;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  min-height: 10%;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <br>
  <p style="text-align:center;">
    <a href="workform.html" target="_blank">Work with us</a>
  </p>
</footer>
```

Thanks in advance. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: `I need a footer to minimize (disappear) when the viewer is at the bottom of the page. So if you haven't scrolled to the bottom yet, you do not see the footer.`

These sentences are contradicting. In the first one you say the footer will disappear when you reach the bottom, in the second sentence you say you do not see the footer until you are at the bottom.

Comment: `bottom`, `left` and `right` in your css have no use. They need a positiong to be active like `position: absolute;`, `position: fixed` or `position: sticky;`. However its complety useless for what you need.  Just place the footer at the bottom of your page and it will eb at the bottom by default. Also a br as first elemnt is a abd use, use `padding-top` instead.

Comment: @DFSFOT Apologies. I worded that wrong. I should've said the latter, I want it to appear when the viewer is at the bottom. Edited.

Comment: @tacoshy This doesn't work. Though the desired result of ebbing is achieved, the element does not even show up on mobile; and is stuck in a fixed position below the text. It will not stick to the window.

Comment: whatb do you want to achieve? at the bottom of the page (entire document) or viewport (screen)?

Comment: Entire document, and have the footer show up when the viewport has reached the end of the document.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the footer at the bottom of the page (document) then use `position: absolute;` on the footer and `position: relative;` on the body:

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

footer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #bdbdbd;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  min-height: 10%;
}


/* for demonstration only */

div {
  min-height: 150vh;
  padding: 10px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>Random content</div>

<footer>
  <br>
  <p style="text-align:center;">
    <a href="workform.html" target="_blank">Work with us</a>
  </p>
</footer>
```

However not to colide with the other element you should add a `margin-bottom` equal the height of the footer to the last element. you can select the alst element with: `body :last-child` as selector.

Comment: You say position fixed in text but code shows position absolute.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need positioning if you just want it to be on the end of your page.
If your content dont has enough height, the user won't get a scrollbar to scroll to the bottom because your page is completely displayed.

```css
footer {
  background-color: #bdbdbd;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Random content</p>
  <p>Random content</p>
  <p>Random content</p>
  <p>Random content</p>
  <p>Random content</p>
  <p>Random content</p>
  <p>Random content</p>
  <p>Random content</p>
  <p>Random content</p>
  <p>Random content</p>
  <p>Random content</p>
  <p>Random content</p>
  <p>Random content</p>
  <p>Random content</p>
  <p>Random content</p>
  <p>Random content</p>
  <p>Random content</p>
  <p>Random content</p>
  <p>Random content</p>
  <p>Random content</p>
  <p>Random content</p>
</div>

<footer>
  <a href="workform.html" target="_blank">Work with us</a>
</footer>
```

Comment: but thats exactly the thing why you should use an absoltue position. it does not relay that there is enough content. Using an absulte positiong adds redundancy for that case.

Comment: This works, there's just a tiny stick in the mud. For desktops, it's possible for the window to be too large, making the footer float there. Thank you so far though- I've learned a lot from you and Tacoshy.